# Elasticsearch with Docker: connect using JDBC / None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jdbc

I started an elasticsearch docker container using the command below. Then I tried connecting using the driver from https://github.com/Anchormen/sql4es

Each time I got "None of the configured nodes are available[127.0.0.1]". What may be wrong ?

The elasticsearch.yml has network.host=0.0.0.0

JDBC URL: jdbc:sql4es://127.0.0.1:9300/sample?cluster.name=docker-cluster

```
docker run --name=elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
```

`curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/http?pretty
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "nodes" : {
    "aTrIrCDtSzmeF1vy6MnUcg" : {
      "name" : "aTrIrCD",
      "transport_address" : "172.17.0.3:9300",
      "host" : "172.17.0.3",
      "ip" : "172.17.0.3",
      "version" : "6.3.2",
      "build_flavor" : "default",
      "build_type" : "tar",
      "build_hash" : "053779d",
      "roles" : [
        "master",
        "data",
        "ingest"
      ],
      "attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "2076528640",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "ml.enabled" : "true"
      },
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : [
          "0.0.0.0:9200"
        ],
        "publish_address" : "172.17.0.3:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      }
    }
  }
}`